# dplyr sample_n from a single group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data where the summary of the number of observations looks like:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   status [2]
   status  year     n
    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1      0  2010  4593
 2      0  2011 10990
 3      0  2012 27711
 4      0  2013 99989
 5      0  2014 95407
 6      0  2015 89010
 7      0  2016 72289
 8      1  2010   584
 9      1  2011   785
10      1  2012   640
11      1  2013   667
12      1  2014   377
13      1  2015   460
14      1  2016   104
```

Where the class of one group is signficantly higher than the class of another group. How can I randomly sample the class of 0 without doing anything to the class of 1. That is, I would like to keep all class 1 observations and randomly sample the class 0 observations by 4593 (which is the minimum number of observations for that year)

Using `group_by(status, year)` and then `sample_n()` doesn't work since the 4593 value is greater than the values in the class 1 group.

Some random sample of my data:

```
    structure(list(status = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    year = c(2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2016, 2013, 2015, 2014, 
    2013, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2014, 2016, 2012, 2013, 2012, 
    2014, 2014, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2016, 2016, 2012, 2016, 2015, 
    2013, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2014, 
    2013, 2012, 2011, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2013, 
    2015, 2012, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2013, 
    2013, 2016, 2016, 2013, 2015, 2012, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2015, 
    2014, 2016, 2016, 2014, 2012, 2016, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2014, 
    2016, 2013, 2016, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2016, 2016, 
    2012, 2014, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2013, 2013, 2015, 2013, 2014, 
    2013, 2015, 2013, 2013, 2011, 2014, 2016, 2013, 2010, 2012, 
    2014, 2012, 2011, 2011, 2013, 2015, 2014, 2010, 2010, 2013, 
    2010, 2014, 2011, 2011, 2014, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2013, 
    2014, 2013, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2013, 2011, 2013, 2012, 2015, 
    2012, 2012, 2012, 2010, 2013, 2013, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 
    2016, 2013, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2014, 2010, 2013, 2014, 
    2011, 2012, 2010, 2012, 2012, 2011, 2015, 2011, 2011, 2013, 
    2015, 2010, 2015, 2011, 2015, 2015, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2012, 
    2014, 2014, 2012, 2012, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2012, 
    2013, 2016, 2014, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
    2014, 2011)), groups = structure(list(status = c(0, 1), .rows = structure(list(
    1:100, 101:200), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by class, n?

Comment: what is your desired output? also "randomly sample the class 0 observations by 4593" does that mean you want `sample_n()` where `size = 4593`?

Comment: Apologies, the class refers to the `status` variable which has 2 clases `0` and `1`. I would like to `group_by` or `filter` the class `0` variable and then take a random sample of these for each year. Using something like `sample_n()` with `size = 4593` is what I am looking for yes, but this does not work when doing `data %>% 
group_by(status, year) %>% sample_n(size = 4593)` since it returns `Error: size must be less or equal than 584 (size of data), set replace = TRUE to use sampling with replacement`. Setting `replace = TRUE` doesn't give me the correct output either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work. `dat` is your example data frame. The code below split the data frame by `status`, and then use `imap` to evaluate if sampling is needed. If the name of the list element is `"0"`, it will conduct sampling. You can change the `size = 1` to the minimum number of your real-world data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  split(f = .$status) %>%
  imap(function(x, y){
    if (y %in% "0"){
      x <- x %>% 
        group_by(status, year) %>%
        sample_n(size = 1) 
    }
    return(x)
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!